# Defragmenting very large db4o database files

Tags: heap-memory, db4o, defragmentation

I have a very large ( 102gb ) db4o .yap file that i am trying to defragment. I keep getting a java heap space error. Is there something i can do to tweak the settings to prevent this? I am already setting the objectCommitFrequency to 10000. I am giving the java process 3 gigs of memory to run this but it still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing which might help is to use the [DatabaseIdMapping](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/defragment/configuration/id_mapping.htm). But I guess you already tried this, no?

```
IdMapping mapping = new DatabaseIdMapping("temporary-mapping.tmp");
DefragmentConfig config = new DefragmentConfig("database.db4o", "database.db4o.back", mapping);

Defragment.defrag(config);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, just saw this now. When i come back to this issue I will give this a try. Thanks again.